# Unicode character is changing on str_replace

Tags: php, unicode, str-replace

Im creating a website with seo friendly url. But when im using `str_replace()` to replace `spaces` with `-`, its changing some unicode charaters.

```
function create_slug($string){
   $slug = str_replace(' ','-', $string);
   return strtolower($slug);
}
```

When `create_slug('Google എഴുത്ത് ഉപകരണങ്ങളുടെ Chrome വിപുലീകരണം');` is called i have to get the output as

> google-എഴുത്ത്-ഉപകരണങ്ങളുടെ-chrome-വിപുലീകരണം

But sometime im getting output as

> google-ഞഴുത്ത്-ഉപകരണങ്ങളു���െ-chrome-വിപുലീകരണം

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: This may be of some use to you http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: Im having problem only sometimes

Comment: in a well formed utf-8 string, this shouldn't be a problem. what encoding are you using?

Comment: Im using UTF-8  Encoding

Comment: then you shouldn't use `strtolower` on it, because it can break the multibyte char

Comment: @Federico Yes , I removed that already.! Now its ok.
Write it  as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server's locale character set setting doesn't support UTF-8, `strtolower` could mistake some valid multibytes sequences as something else. The result would be a corrupt UTF-8 string.

Use [`mb_strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) instead.

```
mb_strtolower($slug, 'UTF-8');
```

If you want that function like `strtolower` and `strtoupper` to only considering characters in the ASCII range, you can overriding your server's locale settings with:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'C');
```

As ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, now the string can be changed with `strtolower` without problems.